# k-Jet of a function $f:R^3 \rightarrow R$

Tags: calculus, optimization, taylor-expansion, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

I am studying this [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/2208.01139). Can someone explain to me why the 4-jet of the function

$U(x, y, z) = x^4 + y^4 - z^6$

is equal to

$(j^{(4)} U)(x, y, z) = x^4 + y^4$

Also, the author says that the origin is an *isolated* critical point of the potential U, and the origin is not a minimum point.

In order to show that it is not a minimum point, I calculated the Hessian, which is the null matrix. How to show that the critical point is isolated? I searched online and found something about Morse's Lemma, is it the right way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function given is $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x, y, z) = x^4 + y^4 - z^6$.

1. **4-jet of the function at the origin**

The 4-jet of the function at the origin is the 4th order Taylor series expansion of the function at the origin. The 4-jet of $f$ at the origin is $x^4 + y^4$, which is the part of the function up to 4th degree terms.

2. **Critical points of the function**

The critical points of the function are the points where the gradient of the function is zero. The gradient of $f$ is given by $\nabla f = (4x^3, 4y^3, -6z^5)$. Setting this to zero gives the critical points. The only critical point of $f$ is at the origin (0, 0, 0).

3. **Check if the origin is an isolated critical point**

The origin is an isolated critical point if there are no other critical points in its immediate vicinity. Since the only critical point of $f$ is at the origin, the origin is an isolated critical point.

4. **Hessian matrix at the origin**

The Hessian matrix of a function is the matrix of its second partial derivatives. The Hessian matrix of $f$ at the origin is a zero matrix, as all second partial derivatives of $f$ at the origin are zero.

5. **Check if the origin is a minimum point**

The origin is a minimum point if the Hessian matrix at the origin is positive definite. Since the Hessian matrix at the origin is a zero matrix, it is not positive definite, and hence the origin is not a minimum point.

This completes the analysis of the function $f(x, y, z) = x^4 + y^4 - z^6$.